# How do you pipe data to curl for URLs in windows environment

Tags: windows, curl, cmd, dockerfile

I'd like to be able to pass URL to curl using cmd pipe in windows environment, so it would be something like this:

```
echo "google.com" | curl
```

this should issue the following command:

```
curl "google.com"
```

Seems kinda trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `curl` reads the URLs from command line, not from standard input stream.

You will need to request `curl` to use a configuration file and then indicate that the file is the standard input stream (use `-` as file name). Also note that a URL in a configuration file (piped or not) needs a `--url` prefix.

So, in your case

```
echo --url "google.com" | curl --config -
```